# Activity is closed after onActivityResult is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

**Activity Explanation:**

Activity_A ... nfc activity that gets started when tag is read

Activity_B ... activity to capture user signature

Hi, my problem goes like that:
I have Activity_A and in that activity I call Activity_B with `startActivityForResult()` method. I then do some work in Activity_B and close it. After that method `onActivityResult()` is called in my Activity_A. I handle the returned data and all is great, but Activity_A is no longer visible.

If I close Activity_B with back button, then Activity_A is still visible. (`onActivityResult()` doesn't get called).

I would like my Activity_A to stay active and visible when I return from Activity_B.

I have tested on 2 devices both running Kitkat (4.4.2 and 4.4.4).
I can't test it on emulator, since Activity_A is NFC activity.

onActivityResult code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult is called");
    switch(requestCode) {
        case SIGNATURE_ACTIVITY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                String signatureFile = data.getStringExtra("SIGNATURE_FILE");
                if(signatureFile !=null ) {
                    this.showToastMessage("Signature captured!");
                    presenter.loadSignatureImage(signatureFile);
                } else {
                    this.showToastMessage("Signature filename not returned!");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: can you please post onActivityResult() code ? or simply try to remove finish() this code from onActivityResult() if is written.

Comment: I added onActivityResult method code

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not using         `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`
before starting the current activity.